# How to prevent Excel from removing trailing zeros after decimal point?

Tags: excel, vba

Whenever i enter 0.9890 in excel sheet and hit enter it shows 0.989 only. I want to retain the text or number as it is in excel sheet. This feature i want to enable through macro for the workbook. How can i do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the customs format.

```
#,##0.0000;-#,##0.0000
```

You can add more zeroes at the end if you want to show more decimal places.

Using a macro:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "#,##0.0000;-#,##0.0000"
End Sub
```

Use this formula to change it to a string, assuming your value is in F20:

```
=TEXT(F20,"#,##0.0000;-#,##0.0000").
```

This will give you a length of 6 as well. As of now, I don't know how to incorporate the same in a macro.

Comment: What should be the syntax if i want to enable it for a column (say B) through macro on a sheet ?

Comment: Used the macro recorder. Updated in answer.

Comment: Your code formats it in the way i want. Thank you for that. But still it's actual value is 0.989 When i checked its length it shows 5. How can i make it to read the length as 6. Basically i want it's value to be exact 0.9890 and not 0.989 Thank you again for your help. Please let me know if it is possible.

Comment: Use this formula to change it to a string, assuming your value is in F20. =TEXT(F20,"#,##0.0000;-#,##0.0000"). This will give you a length of 6 as well. As of now, I don't know how to incorporate the same in a macro.